# Update the index in a list<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, string, list, listbox

I have a listBox which holds items with values from two seperate lists `NameList` & `DescriptionList`.

when i select an item it displays some information like "name" and "description" from the item at a selectedIndex.

If i remove one string in the top all the strings will mess up by index and show wrong values. Can you update the index of `list<string>` ?

I tried using `Label.Content = NameList[listBox.SelectedItem];` but it just gives argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'.

**Edit 1**

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> CallNameList = Control.NameList;
    List<string> CallDescList = Control.DescriptionList;
           
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
    {
        TextLabel.Text = "Please select another item";
    }
    else
    {
        TitelLabel.Content = CallNameList[listBox.SelectedIndex]; 
        TextLabel.Text = CallDescList[listBox.SelectedIndex]; 
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first scene i've got the numbers 1-2-3-4. Here it displays 1 when i selected 1.
[image: Picture two]

However when i delete 1 and then select 3 as in the picture it outputs that as 2
[image: Picture one]

This is because the index drops by one for all. Making object 3 -> object 2, etc.

How can i solve this??

Comment: can you add the full block of code where the error occurs?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the error is you are trying to use SelectedItem (object) instead of SelectedIndex (int)

```
  Label.Content = NameList[listBox.SelectedIndex];
```

or you could just get a value from the SelectedItem

```
  Label.Content = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: I am adding the item the following way 

--- main.listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1} ", name, now)); ---

In this case name is the string and now is DateTime.Now... So i cant use listbox.selecteditem.tostring(); because it will display to much information (the time). Is there a way to update the indexes in a list<string>?

Comment: To clear things up. When i use SelectedIndex i can the value displayed just the way i want it. Only the string from the NameList. But once i delete a string i get the wrong index in the other strings. This is why i wondered if you could use SelectedItem or update list<string> index

Comment: you can use `listBox.SelectedItem.Name` .. is that what you want?

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis I dont get any option to use `listBox.SelectedItem.Name`. 
I edited my question now

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some `DataBinding`. Using index, and synchronizing two lists with it is.... not very convenient.

We can consider that you have objects related to your date.
So I created a class:

```
public class CustomDate
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public CustomDate(string iName, string iDescription)
    {
        this.name = iName;
        this.description = iDescription;
    }
}
```

Then I used an `ObservableCollection` to handle these objects. It's similar to a `List`, but will handle the adding/removing of elements very smoothly.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<CustomDate> CallNameList = new ObservableCollection<CustomDate>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CallNameList.Add(new CustomDate("Date #1", "Description of first date"));
        CallNameList.Add(new CustomDate("Date #2", "This is a fantastic date"));
        CallNameList.Add(new CustomDate("Date #3", "It will rain today"));

        MyList.DataContext = CallNameList;
    }

    private void Delete_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CallNameList.Remove((CustomDate)MyList.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML/WPF part. You should focus on the `DataBinding` part. If you're not familiar with it, you should find and read some tutorials. WPF without DataBinding is pointless.

```
<Window x:Class="StackTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Laser Control " Height="300" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Cursor="Arrow" Width="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Name="Delete" Click="Delete_Click_1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Delete current date"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=SelectedItem.name}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=SelectedItem.description}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

This way to do is not the only one, but I find it very convenient since the `DataBinding` is taking care of every thing for me. And it would be very easy to add more information, or modify the UI without modifying the logic behind it.